# What is limit of data that can be passed with jQuery ajax GET request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, cross-domain

This is the cross-domain request to the REST service:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType: "application/javascript",
                data: d,
                //crossDomain: true,
                async: false,
                url:"http://xx.xx.xx.xx/MyService/MyService.svc/GetData",
                success: function (jsonData) {
                    console.log(jsonData);
                    alert('Hello');
                },
                complete: function (request, textStatus) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                },
                error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
});
```

Here, with `data: d` how much data I can send? Is there a limit?

Comment: [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request), [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: thats an easy but good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser limit:
               It varies by browser. HTTP standards itself does not impose a limit.
               IE8 limit is 2,083 chars. Firefox supports much higher limits.

Web servers impose their own limit which are usually configurable. I think it is 2048 bytes for iis.